# Why is Mobaxterm not copying all my lines in my clipboard?

Tags: ssh, vi, mobaxterm

I have trouble copying the lines i have in my clipboard into Mobaxterm (In a VI file with Unix) since it is not copying all my lines, only certain amount and may cut a line in half at the end

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for copy all lines to clipboard using a VI editor could be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard